# Retrieve array values from mongodb with Java

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

i have the following code :

```
DBCollection collsc = db.getCollection("StudentCourses") ;
BasicDBObject querysc = new BasicDBObject("StudentID",id ); 
DBCursor curssc = collsc.find(querysc);

while(curssc.hasNext()) {

    DBObject e = curssc.next();
    System.out.println("You are currently registered for the following modules: ") ; 
    System.out.println(e.get("CoursesRegistered")) ; 

}
```

This outputs:

```
You are currently registered for the following modules: 
[ "DigitalLogic" "OperatingSystems" , "FundamentalsCSE"]
```

However i want only the values to be returned from the array, i.e, DigitalLogic, OperatingSystems and FundamentalsCSE. I will use these values to populate a JList. Help please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to use

```
BasicDBList e = (BasicDBList) curssc.next().get("CoursesRegistered");
```

instead of

```
DBObject e = curssc.next();
```

and then get value from e.getIndex(index);

Comment: It doesn't work. I get exception as follows : 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.BasicDBObject cannot be cast to com.mongodb.BasicDBList
 at modules.RegistrationSystem.main(RegistrationSystem.java:80)

Comment: Still exceptions. 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys, not: [CoursesRegistered]
 at org.bson.types.BasicBSONList._getInt(BasicBSONList.java:161)
 at org.bson.types.BasicBSONList._getInt(BasicBSONList.java:152)
 at org.bson.types.BasicBSONList.get(BasicBSONList.java:104)
 at modules.RegistrationSystem.main(RegistrationSystem.java:82)

Comment: This did it. 
    DBCollection collsc = db.getCollection("StudentCourses") ;
    BasicDBObject querysc = new BasicDBObject("StudentID",id ); 
    DBCursor curssc = collsc.find(querysc);
    
    while(curssc.hasNext()) {
     
     //DBObject e = curssc.next();
     BasicDBList e = (BasicDBList) curssc.next().get("CoursesRegistered");
     System.out.println("You are currently registered for the following modules: ") ; 
     
     for (int i=0;i<e.size();i++) {
      
     System.out.println(e.get(i)) ; 
     
     }
    }

Comment: How do i do this this with mongo-java 3.0 driver ?